# SourceTree: Error when opening repository (OSX)

Tags: macos, git, symbols, atlassian-sourcetree

When I open SourceTree and try to open my repositories (or cloning then opening) then I get this error:

```
'git log' failed with code 5:'

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

'
```

I have Command Line Tools installed ([the answer here suggests its needed](https://www.ngxo.com/thread/20929689)). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that SourceTree uses an embedded version of Git by default. It can be different from the system version, and can fail in some circumstances.

One of the easiest way to cope with the issue is to tell SourceTree to use the system Git:

```
Preferences > Git > button "Use System Git"
```